pyOpenMS How to add/remove features from feature_map or concensus_map?
I want to add/remove features from an existing pyOpenMS.FeatureMap() or pyOpenMS.ConcensusMap() object.
I tried things like:
new_feature_map = pyOpenMS.FeatureMap()
for f in feature_map:
   new_feature_map += f

but I cannot seem to find a way to create a new FeatureMap() from Feature() objects.

Got the answer. The push_back() method is needed:
new_feature_map = pyOpenMS.FeatureMap()
for f in feature_map:
   new_feature_map.push_back(f)

